# create a list from a list of list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist, append

I know this is probably simple but i'm having a hard time doing it,
all i'm trying to do make a new list of list  from an existing list of list full of tuples , for example:

```
listA = [ [(1,2,A), (1,3,B)], [(1,1,B),(1,2,D)], [(1,1,C),(1,3,F], [(1,3,D),(1,5,F)] ]
```

and I want to make a new list to be composed of a list of list of the [2] element (the letters) from the original list.

so my new list would look like :

```
newList = [ [A,B] , [B,D], [C,F], [D,F] ]
```

I hope this is clear.

Comment: Please include what you've tried and why/how your attempt failed.

Comment: And please post code that works by copy and pasting and won't cause a `NameError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have converted you variables `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` to strings for providing an example output. You can use a single list comprehension then as follows.

**Explanation**: You loop over individual sublists using `i`. Each sublist have two tuples, of which you want the last elements. `i[0][-1]` gives you the last element of *first* tuple and `i[0][-1]` gives you the last element of *second* tuple,

```
listA = [ [(1,2,'A'), (1,3,'B')], [(1,1,'B'),(1,2,'D')], [(1,1,'C'),(1,3,'F')], [(1,3,'D'),(1,5,'F')] ]
listB = [[i[0][-1], i[1][-1]] for i in listA]
```

outputs

```
[['A', 'B'], ['B', 'D'], ['C', 'F'], ['D', 'F']]
```

Comment: I shoulda had made it more clear but thanks I got It now , the code you showed me worked but it only accounts for 2 tuples , which they vary everytime , I shoulda stated this

Comment: i did "for bracket in listA: newlist.append([bracket[i][-1] for i in  range(len(bracket))])" and that gave me what i wanted . But you pointed me in the right direction so thank you !

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following nested comprehension:

```
[[y[2] for y in x] for x in listA]
# [['A', 'B'], ['B', 'D'], ['C', 'F'], ['D', 'F']]
```

The inner comprehension has the added flexibility of working for inner lists of any length.

Answer (score 0):

If `numpy` is allowed you could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

listA = [[(1, 2, 'A'), (1, 3, 'B')], [(1, 1, 'B'), (1, 2, 'D')], [(1, 1, 'C'), (1, 3, 'F')], [(1, 3, 'D'), (1, 5, 'F')]]
print(np.array(listA)[:, :, 2].tolist())
```

**Output**

```
[['A', 'B'], ['B', 'D'], ['C', 'F'], ['D', 'F']]
```

As an alternative you could also do:

```
print(np.array(listA)[..., 2].tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a condensed expression with `list` or using list comprehension

```
print(list([j[-1] for j in i] for i in lista))
print([[j[-1] for j in i] for i in lista])
```

Expaneded explanation:

```
new = []
for i in lista:
    x = []
    for j in i:
        x.append(j[-1])
    new.append(x)
```